# Android ExpandableListView - Looking for a tutorial

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to program an Android interface which uses an expandable list on the side and a fragment on the other side so I can load different resources by clicking on the children of the expandable list. But unfortunately I cannot find any good tutorials about this list anywhere. Yes I've look in the API demos and I've made a normal list with a BaseExpandableListAdapter but still, understanding those list well it's kinda hard without a good tutorial, do you have any good one around or info I could check?

Comment: I can't believe this was marked as "not constructive"!  It was very constructive, and the answers very helpful! Thanks for posting this question, DeX03.

Comment: I believe this flag was because you don't ask questions on StackOverflow that you can easily research yourself.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you can find working example of the expandable list view by following links:

- [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)
- [Expandable ListView in ANDROID](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)
- [Android Expandable ListView simple Example in android.](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)

for click on child, you can handle this way.

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {                
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) { 
        // your code...
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks..

Comment: but that doesn't work the same way for activities which do not extend ExpandableListActivity because that's what i have, how do i fixed to work in that one?

Comment: nevermind i just fixed it, great help!

Answer (score 66):

**Create item list**

```
List<ParentItem> itemList = new ArrayList<ParentItem>();

ParentItem parent1 = new ParentItem();
parent1.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());
parent1.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());
parent1.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());

ParentItem parent2 = new ParentItem();
parent2.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());
parent2.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());
parent2.getChildItemList().add(new ChildItem());

itemList.add(parent1);
itemList.add(parent2);

ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter = new ExpandableListViewAdapter(context, itemList);
```

**Data Objects**

```
public class ParentItem {

        private List<ChildItem> childItemList;

        public ParentItem() {
                childItemList = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();
        }

        public List<ChildItem> getChildItemList() {
                return childItemList;
        }
}

public class ChildItem {
        // filll with your data
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private static final class ViewHolder {
                TextView textLabel;
        }

        private final List<ParentItem> itemList;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ParentItem> itemList) {
                this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.itemList = itemList;
        }

        @Override
        public ChildItem getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

                return itemList.get(groupPosition).getChildItemList().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return itemList.get(groupPosition).getChildItemList().size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                                 final ViewGroup parent) {
                View resultView = convertView;
                ViewHolder holder;


                if (resultView == null) {

                        resultView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.test_list_item, null); //TODO change layout id
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.textLabel = (TextView) resultView.findViewById(android.R.id.title); //TODO change view id
                        resultView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) resultView.getTag();
                }

                final ChildItem item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

                holder.textLabel.setText(item.toString());

                return resultView;
        }

        @Override
        public ParentItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return itemList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
                return itemList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(final int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View theConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View resultView = theConvertView;
                ViewHolder holder;

                if (resultView == null) {
                        resultView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.test_list_item, null); //TODO change layout id
                        holder = new ViewHolder();
                        holder.textLabel = (TextView) resultView.findViewById(android.R.id.title); //TODO change view id
                        resultView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                        holder = (ViewHolder) resultView.getTag();
                }

                final ParentItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);

                holder.textLabel.setText(item.toString());

                return resultView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
        }

}
```

**Gives you**

```
==============================
+Parent 1
==============================
-child 1.1
==============================
-child 1.2
==============================
-child 1.3
==============================
+Parent 2
==============================
-child 2.1
==============================
-child 2.2
==============================
-child 2.3
==============================
```

Comment: but, how can i handle the click event on the children of the lists? cause that's the main issue with all the tutorials i've found

Comment: `Semi colon(;)` missing `<ParentItem> itemList = new ArrayList<ParentItem>()`

Comment: I'm getting null `holder.textLabel.setText(item.toString());`, How fixed it?

Comment: It means "holder.textLabel" is null, are you are inflating it correct?

Comment: Yes, your code is just pasted. I got compile time error at `private static final class ViewHolder` that is `The member type ViewHolder cannot be declared static; static types can only be declared in static or top level types`, after i have removed `static`, it gives me run time error.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is the same data structure I am using, but I couldn't find any examples that validated it would work.  One dumb question though.  When the data changes, how do you tell the adapter to update the ExpandableListView?  Would you add an updateData(List<> data) method?  If so, what triggers the list update?  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWard call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Perfect, simple and well-explained implementation. Although, if you've a complex layout for the child (not just a textview), how will you create a separate viewholder for it?

Comment: How do I fill data For ParentItem as Heading and fill data For ChildItem ?

Answer (score 1):

This way you can handle events:

```
getExpandableListView().setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
{               
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, 
        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
    { 
        // your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: irrelevant answer....