# Directory listing muliplechoice select list

Tags: android

I've created an activity which will show the multiple-choice list of all the directories in my phone.
Till now, I've only managed to show the list of only parent folders.
I want when the user clicks of an item (not on the check-box), it should expand to show its sub-folders (also multiple choice list).
This is what I've made till now.

```
Parent1
Parent2
Parent3
Parent4
```

I want if user selects Parent1, then it expands with sub-folder as:

```
Parent1
- Sub-Folder1
- Sub-Folder2
Parent2
Parent3
Parent4
```

Below is my code till now:

```
public class DirectoryListing extends Activity {

    ListView dirlv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directorylisting);
        try {
            ArrayList<String> dirList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            dirList = getAllDirList();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android.R.id.text1,
                    dirList);
            dirlv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDirList);
            dirlv.setAdapter(adapter);
            dirlv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<String> getAllDirList() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        File home = new File("/");
        File[] files = home.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                result.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simple ListView use [Expandable Listview](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+expandable+listview+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=aTQ&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sa=X&ei=gz_0T4nAMsLorQeFv_zWBg&ved=0CDgQBSgA&q=android+expandablelistview+example&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=df4f14c76f997e44&biw=1366&bih=664).

Go through this link http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

and this SO question [Android ExpandableListView - Looking for a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial)