# Styling the android listview with array list adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, styles

I have written the code for creating a list out of some arrays shown below!
code runs properly and output is as expected!

**update for people with same prob:** [nice tutorial for custom listview](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] items = { "some", "fancy", "items", "to", "show" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, items);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="22dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

**what I want to accomplish?**

1. change color and font of the text in each list item to a different one..and do some task on tapping on them...
2. also is it possible to get another listview inside the same listview
   eg. if I click on a list item it again shows me a list (kind of a sub list) with different list items on that same activity(or screen).and some action could be done on tapping the sub list items.

**Detailed answers are appreciated as I am new to android development..
Thanks!**

Comment: Are you talking about _Customized ListView_.?

Comment: yes! a listView which could be easily customized and which works with arrayadapter

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Comment: if >>>Customized ListView.?     is a link it is broken!

Comment: In comment.? No, its not a link, I have provided a link for it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.change color and font of the text in each list item to a different one..and do some task on 
  tapping on them...
```

- Make a Custom Adapter, override `getVIew()` of that adapter and make 
  changes on color and text in it.
- override `onItemClick()` for your ListView. to accomplish click event
  for list item.

Now

```
2. also is it possible to get another listview inside the same listview eg. if I click on a
   list item it again shows me a list (kind of a sub list) with different list items on that
   same activity(or screen).and some action could be done on tapping the sub list items.

3. what are my other list styling options..
```

- Its a [**Expandable ListView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) Just look at link for more
  information.

And [Tutorial](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html)

Comment: could you provide a simmple sample code or refer me to site containing that sample! google searching doesn't provide me with understandable stuff

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into a custom ArrayAdapter as seen here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

That will take care of the first and third questions. As for the second one that's not possible with the default implementation of ListView but there are libraries that enable you to create drop down listItems.

Answer (score 0):

For 1st question, you can use paulthom12345' answer.

2nd question: You have to use [exapandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

for more details please see: [Android ExpandableListView - Looking for a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial)

3rd question is not constructive and very vague. Please edit the question and explain in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [Customized List View](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) for it.
2. It is not exactly possible to have a list inside a list. Instead of it, use [expandable list](http://androidsourcecodemj.blogspot.in/2012/10/how-to-use-expandable-list-in-android.html)
3. Have a look at [Android Listview with different layout for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777306/1626878)