# Android dropdown list

Tags: android, xml

Hi i'm trying to create a GUI like in image. I created this with photoshop. I searched on internet but nothing, can you help me with some tutorial or anything else. Thanks for help!

[image: I created this with Ps]

Comment: What you are looking for is an accordion. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10313432/1253844.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - accordion widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161999/android-accordion-widget)

Answer (score 3):

My immediate thoughts:

`ViewPager` – For the sections – [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) & [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

`ExpandableListView`  - For the expandable menus - [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) & look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial)

`ImageView` or `ImageButton` – For the image – [view docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html), [button docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html). Maybe you could also take a look at [`NinePatch`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) & [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html))

`EditText` – For the input boxes – [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) is a good beginners guide for Android development, which also shows how to use EditTexts and different other things.

There are other solutions, but this should give you a chance to find more by yourself on the internet. 
See what you can come up with and ask again if you have put some *effort* into a *specific* problem, but you cant seem to solve it.

EDIT: Just realized you might just be looking for the dropdown list. Oh well, hope you can use the rest anyways.