# Changing ListView to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

I have a `ListView` in my Activity but now I want to change it to an `ExpandableListView`. Do I need to change my listview completely or can I add expandableListView to my existing listView?

Comment: Expandable listview is nothing but listview itself, but you will need to change the view as well as it's adapter also.

Comment: @Sameer: But how do I do that?

Comment: @Spackplug: there are many example available on google. and also i am posting my own example as answer to your question. please check that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example i used.. you can change it and use it.

// ListView code

```
public class FevList extends ExpandableListActivity {
        String title;
        String url;
        SQLiteDatabase database;
        DbUtil db;
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> subjectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            try {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.exlist);
                db = new DbUtil();
                database = db.openConnection(this);
                // Thread for getting values of title from DataBase.
                SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                        this, createGroupList(), R.layout.group_row,
                        new String[] { "subject" }, new int[] { R.id.row_name },
                        createChildList(), R.layout.child_row,
                        new String[] { "title" }, new int[] { R.id.grp_child });
                setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
                registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



 // code for adapter



/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                private List createGroupList() {

    // write your code here.

                    return (List) result;

                }

                /* creatin the HashMap for the children */

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                private List createChildList() {

    // write your code here.
                    return result;
                }

                public void onContentChanged() {

                    System.out.println("onContentChanged");

                    super.onContentChanged();

                }

                /* This function is called on each child click */

                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

    // write your code here.

                    return true;

                }

                /* This function is called on expansion of the group */

                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

                    try {

                        System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = "
                                + groupPosition);

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class PharmaciesListScreen extends ExpandableListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ExpandableListView expandbleLis = getExpandableListView();

        List<RegionItem> regionsList = new RegionsDBUtils(getApplication())
                .getAllRegions();

        PharmaciesListAdapter mNewAdapter = new PharmaciesListAdapter(regionsList);
        mNewAdapter
                .setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        getExpandableListView().setAdapter(mNewAdapter);
    }
```

Adapter code:

```
public class PharmaciesListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       //set up here you child elements.
       //you can use inflater here
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        }
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(mRegionsList.get(groupPosition).region);
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}
}
```

Note: in adapter you'll need to implement more methods.
Also, take a look at this post:
[Android ExpandableListView - Looking for a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

["Here is a pretty good example for ExpandableListView"](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

ExpandableListView inherits from ListView. It add more things to the ListView implementation like expanding and collapsing property, header and child views etc. When moving from listView to expandable list view you'll need to make changes in :

1. XML view
2. Adapter to implement ExpandableListAdapter
3. While Setting the adapter you'll need to new ExpandableListAdapter(this, list of DataHeader for each list, list of DataChild that you want to populate beneath each header);