# Show and hide multiple textviews

Tags: android

[image]I need to show/hide four textviews on pressing four buttons. The functionality is visible in pictures. In iOS I used button. But for android,can I use some sort of list view or something else suitable to thisenter image description here? 
!First and second buttons are pressed here while third and fourth are not yet. Again pressing the button that is already pressed,text hides][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZX6W.png)

Comment: you can do it like in iOS using button + textview below button.. also to show hide element in android check tag visibility..

Comment: What you are looking for is an expandable list view. Some resources: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834782/827110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is a very good example on `Custom ExpandibleList` in Github.

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView

Hope this will help you to achieve `smooth animation and collapse`.

You need to change the layout as your requirement.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Using ExpandableListView, you can have groups and childs, and you can expand and collapse any groups you want.

For example:

```
mExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
```

Comment: I ve checked examples for expandablelistview, they all show single word or one line text,not a textview for multiple lines, is there a good tutorial for that?

Comment: what do you mean by single word or one line text?