# How to populate an ExpandableListView with ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to dynamically populate an ExpandableListView with an ArrayList for the group of the view and an ArrayList> for the item view. I managed to get it working how I want it with fixed String arrays with dummy data, but as I will be dealing with these objects as ArrayLists all of the time, I wanted to keep it like that. I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1 at the moment. I have been trying to get this working for a while now and I have done a lot of searching and haven't really found any information on it that is applicable to what I want to do and how you can do it. Please can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code and I have kept the fixed string arrays in to show what I want as ArrayLists and the code commented out that worked with the string arrays:

```
public class ConfigAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
private Activity activity;
public String []groupList = {"Group1", "Group2", "Group3", "Group4", 
                              "Group5", "Group6", "Group7"}; // String array for parent list text views
public String [][]childList = {
        {
            "Child1", "Child2", "Child3", "Child4"
        },
        {
            "Child1", "Child2"
        },
        {
            "Child1", "Child2"
        },
        {
            "Child1", "Child2", "Child3"
        },
        {
            "Child1", "Child2", "Child3"
        },
        {
            "Child1"
        },
        {
            "Child1", "Child2", "Child3"
        }

}; // String array for child list text views
public String[][] dataObjectList = {
            {
                "1", "2", "3", "4"
            },
            {
                "2348", "2442"
            },
            {
                "1", "2"
            },
            {
                "1", "2", "3"
            },
            {
                "24234", "23432", "6567"
            },
            {
                "1"
            },
            {
                "1", "2", "3"
            }
};

private ArrayList<String> groupStrings;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> itemStrings;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> dataObjectStrings;

public ConfigAdapter()
{
    assert "Default constructor not used." != null; // Assert to prompt not to use this constructor.
}

public ConfigAdapter(Activity refActivity) 
{
    activity = refActivity;

    groupStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemStrings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    dataObjectStrings = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
}

public void setGroupStrings(ArrayList<String> refGroupStrings)
{
    groupStrings = refGroupStrings;
}

public void setItemStrings(ArrayList<String> refItemStrings)
{
    itemStrings.add(refItemStrings);
}

public void setDataObjectStrings(ArrayList<String> refDataObjectStrings)
{
    dataObjectStrings.add(refDataObjectStrings);
}

public ArrayList<String> getGroupStrings()
{
    return groupStrings;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getItemStrings()
{
    return itemStrings;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getDataObjectStrings()
{
    return dataObjectStrings;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater childLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View childView = childLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.config_child_list_view, null);
    TextView itemTextView = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.configListTextView1);
    itemTextView.setText(itemStrings.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
    //itemTextView.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    final ViewSwitcher childViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) childView.findViewById(R.id.configListViewSwitcher);
    final TextView dataObjectTextView = (TextView) childViewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.configListTextView2);
    dataObjectTextView.setText(dataObjectStrings.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
    //dataObjectTextView.setText(dataObjectList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    System.out.println("Group position: " + groupPosition);
    System.out.println("Child position: " + childPosition);
    System.out.println("Data object list: " + dataObjectList.length);
    final EditText dataObjectEditText = (EditText) childViewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.configEditText1);
    dataObjectEditText.setHint("hello");

    childViewSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(childViewSwitcher.getCurrentView() == dataObjectTextView)
            {
                childViewSwitcher.showNext();
            }

        }
    });
    {

    }

    return childView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    return childList[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() 
{
    return groupList.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    TextView tvParent = new TextView(activity);
    tvParent.setText(groupStrings.get(groupPosition));
    //tvParent.setText(groupList[groupPosition];
    tvParent.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);
    tvParent.setTextSize(18);
    tvParent.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); // Sets text to bold

    return tvParent;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() 
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to this [reference link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

it will help you.

Comment: I tried this and it makes sense to me, but it still comes up with the same error. Any advice?

Comment: @JamesMeade Sorry, If you give me some time I will check it later, because now I will log out

Comment: Thank you very much. I have also worked out that I had done my method wrong and need to look over it to correct it. I will let you know if that fixes the problem or not.

Comment: I solved my problem by creating methods in a custom object class that I had to get the array list of strings from objects associated with that object class and then updated the fields in the expandable list view with those array lists. I also did this by using the example of the link you suggested. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome James. It's my pleasure my little help you consider.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial), but i know there are many other threads with same question on stack overflow.