# Android ListView of Messages(Not a sublist in a list thing like EXPANDABLE LISTVIEW,but a full view)

Tags: android, listview

[**Like this:**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eOIexvK2SU) 
I am working with  list view in android having short messages in  it,When I click an item from  the list vieW a new activity is started which shows the full description of the message along with additional information.However I want to achieve something like the following image,that when some message from the list view is clicked,then the message will be displayed as in the image rather than starting a new activity.Is there any predefined component there ?If not then how can I achieve it?
**I don't know how to show the full message on the same screen in a listview**

---

[image].

Comment: I believe that's called an *ExpandableListView* or sometimes an *Accordion*.

Comment: @jww **My full message(as shown in the image) may consist of a complete email message**,,,then will your expandable listview will work there too....?

Comment: Thanks for posting a question with example snap but unfortunately this question has been asked many time. You need to look for **ExpandableListView**.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ExpandableListView`. Tutorial links can be found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial).

Comment: You could also use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: @eightx2 - why did you *not* move to close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: I guess my requirement is the fragment thing as @Abbath is suggesting

Comment: @jww My full message(as shown in the image) may consist of a complete email message,,,then will your expandable listview will work there too....?