# Expandable list view with parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, expandablelistview

How can I implement expandable list view with text and images in my android app when I am getting data from parse.com?

I managed to achieve getting data from parse.com while in a list view but now expandable list view is my worst nightmare.

Comment: i need you help please.

Comment: What you got? Start with the code to call `expandablelistview` and where the data from `parse.com` comes in

Comment: When I fetch data from parse.com  .The data appear in a listview.  Then I want the data to appear in my layout in expandable form

Comment: I thought of creating two table in parse.com when the are connected with a certain entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several good sources for making expandable list view:

A [custom Expandable ListView](http://android-adda.blogspot.in/2011/06/custom-expandable-listview.html), [another custom Expanadable ListView tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

Some tutorial [from a SO answer, the links (copied)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834782/928952):

> - [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)
> - [Expandable ListView in ANDROID](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)
> - [Android Expandable ListView simple Example in android](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html)