# Dynamic way to create List<> at runtime and add values in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new in android. I have expandable list view of course in which a topic has n lectures and add data like this:

```
List<String> Topic1 = new ArrayList<String>();
Topic1.add("Lecture 1");
Topic1.add("Lecture 2");
Topic1.add("Lecture 3");
Topic1.add("Lecture 4");
Topic1.add("Lecture 5");

List<String> Topic2 = new ArrayList<String>();
Topic2.add("Lecture 1");
Topic2.add("Lecture 2");
Topic2.add("Lecture 3");
Topic2.add("Lecture 4");
Topic2.add("Lecture 5");

List<String> Topic3 = new ArrayList<String>();
Topic3.add("Lecture 1");
Topic3.add("Lecture 2");
Topic3.add("Lecture 3");
Topic3.add("Lecture 4");
Topic3.add("Lecture 5");

expandableListDetail.put("Topic 1", Topic1);
expandableListDetail.put("Topic 2", Topic2);
expandableListDetail.put("Topic 3", Topic3);
```

But I want efficient way to create List and add values at run time if there is more Topics and its lectures but didn't get how to do that.

Comment: Make a **local json** file and parse from it, or move your logic to server side and consume it through API service.

Comment: Try out RecyclerView'

Comment: Use ExpandableListAdapter, sample is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824382/5612090

Comment: thankyou but its static way that currently I follow @antygravity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this if your app is server side:
First create List of list

```
List<List<String>> topicDataList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Create parent and child List and insert response data in it and then

```
for (int j = 0; j < parentList.size(); j++) {
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < childList.size(); i++) {

                    tempList.add(childList.get(i).getChild_name());

                }
            }
            topicDataList.add(tempList);

        }
        for (int k = 0; k < parentList.size(); k++) {

            expandableListDetail.put(parentList.get(k).getChild_name(), topicDataList.get(k));
        }
return expandableListDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RecyclerView instead, its like a ListView but way more functional. You just create an Adapter class to handle all your items and then whenever your list is updated, the changes are propagated throughout by calling adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Here's a good article on getting started, [Recycler View Basics](https://thecodingcreative.co/2019/android-studio/mastering-the-recycler-view/).